# How to make node.js check function and throw an error after it called?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I am currently working on a bot, and I'm experiencing an error. Node.js looks at the code and throws an error, because the image isn't there yet (it will download in process).

```
client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.photo) {
    const chat_id = msg.chat.id
    const file_id = msg.photo[(msg.photo.length-1)].file_id;
    const FileInf = await client.getFile(file_id)
    var date = Date.now()
    const imageFileName = `download_image_${date}.png`;
    URLlink = `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot${BotToken}/${FileInf.file_path}`;
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: URLlink,
      responseType: 'stream',
    })
      .then(async (response) => {
        
        var image = await response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imageFileName));
        sizeOf(image, async (err, dimensions) => {
          console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height); //TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'width')
        }); 
      })
        .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error downloading image:', error);
        });
    
  };
});
```

I was expecting this code to download the image first, and then it would check the dimensions.
Any ideas?